# What is the meaning of the phrase "be keyed upon something"?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/V43mSQEjZY8). It is at 6 minute and 40 second. Here is the context:

> But for those who have been, maybe, **keyed upon** this stuff or heard us discuss it before, or kind of tracking this concept of pain as output of the brain instead of input to the brain.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. He said

> But for those who have **been**, maybe, **keyed up** on this stuff or heard us discuss it before...

"be keyed up" [means](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/key)

*Be nervous, tense, or excited, especially before an important event.*

2. He wanted to say

> But for those who **have keyed upon** this stuff or heard us discuss it before...

where "key (in) on/upon" [means](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/key-in-on)

*to focus one's attention, effort, etc. on*